# Intelligent Code Completion outside of programming environments

Tags: ms-word, autocomplete, completion, bibliography

I can't go to sleep until I post this...My wife is still up at 1:20 AM working on a bibliography for a HUGE doctoral paper.  All ya'll going through academia know the feeling...In the meantime, she took a break to casually mention the shortcomings of MS Word's bibliography database system, and the redundant boring retyping of all the same authors, titles, and publishers.

But this late at night, I make the connection that programming environments have been auto completing text for years.  It's just how it works.  Read the included headers, when you start typing, pop up a menu of potential matches until you select one or finish typing.  Why can't this be the way to write bibliographies?

So, my apologies for a LMGTFY question, but when I do literally google that, I get only tutorials telling you how to fill out the reference tools in Word.  Honestly, I think something like this would be a game changer for many...and if it's not been created, why not?

------Project outline--------

Text Document, define a "bibliography" namespace, where the full citations exist in a syntax based on the formatting guidelines.  Each new line is pretty much a function definition, which has an abbreviation area.  Then throughout the document, when you insert a citation (parenthesis or footnote) the text editor starts polling the bibliography, and provides you with all that intuitive autocompletion that doesn't screw up...we depend on it, now it's time to share the wealth.

So I'm really almost flabbergasted if this type of use for Intelligent Code Completion hasn't been implemented in some form.  Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: Hey @chrisroode, this is not a discussion forum but a QnA...there doesn't seem to be a clear conclusive question on this..

Comment: You could, of course use a third-party referencing addin like Endnote, Zotero, etc., which allow references to be downloaded. Moreover, unlike what you get with Word, their references will at least conform to the relevant standards. Word's Chicago implementation, for example, is abysmal. APA's better, but still faulty

Comment: The xml for a typical reference in Word looks like: <b:Source xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography"><b:Tag>Dav04</b:Tag><b:SourceType>Book</b:SourceType><b:Guid>{E560DE8F-DFF4-4326-9E22-A740C21EF146}</b:Guid><b:Author><b:Author><b:NameList><b:Person><b:Last>Davidson</b:Last><b:First>G</b:First></b:Person></b:NameList></b:Author></b:Author><b:Title>Roget's Thesaurus</b:Title><b:Year>2004</b:Year><b:City>London</b:City><b:Publisher>Penguin Books</b:Publisher></b:Source>